# Django and Crispy Forms- Can not get default value to work in Radio Select widget.

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

Using Django and Crispy forms I am trying to make a initial/default value for my radio select widget in regions field.

I was told that the best way to do this is to do give the form class the 'initial' value when it is created. I tried this and I get `'CreateForm' object is not callable`. I've also tried it in the form itself by giving it as an extra argument in the region field but didn't have success with that ether.

views.py:

```
class CreateRequest(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Request
    fields = ['region', 'ddi', 'zen_desk_ticket', 'user_assigned', 'user_requester', 'date_due', 'description']
    template_name = "requests_app/create_request.html"
    obj = Region.objects.get(name='Chicago')
    form_class = CreateForm(initial = {"region": unicode(obj.pk)})
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        objects = form.save()
        return super(CreateRequest, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateForm(ModelForm):
    date_due = forms.DateTimeField(
            widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM",
                                          "pickTime": True}))

    region = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset= Region.objects.all(),
            empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        exclude = ('completed', 'date_completed')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2 control-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-4'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset('Create',
                     'region',
                     'user_assigned',
                     'user_requester',
                     'date_due',
                     'description',
            ),

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary')
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place to set arguments for your form is the `get_form_kwargs` method. For example:

```
class YourView(CreateView):
    form = YourFormClass  # no arguments here

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(YourViewName, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['initial'] = {}  # your initial data here
        return kwargs
```